# How to know which version of VC++ runtime is required by a C++/CLI assembly?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, .net-assembly

I have a C++/CLI assembly and it somehow needs `msvcr120.dll` (which is part of VC++ redistributable package 2013) to run. I discovered this by using tools to monitor which files the process is trying to load during running. Is there a way to get the required VC++ runtime version by looking into the dll and without running it? I tried to use `ildasm.exe` to look at the metadata but did not find relavant information.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a mixed module (`/clr`), then the C Runtime will show up in its load-time dependencies:

```
dumpbin /dependents mymodule.dll
```

If it's a pure module (`/clr:pure`), then calls into the C Runtime will be via P/Invoke.  You can disassemble the module and search for P/Invoke wrappers:

```
ildasm /text mymodule.dll | findstr pinvokeimpl
```

This will list the modules that may be dynamically loaded to satisfy P/Invoke calls.  If the module depends on a C Runtime, you'll see it show up numerous times (you can further filter the list by searching for "msvcr" or "msvcp" if you're specifically interested in the Visual C++ libraries).

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an alternative, you may also find the information using a tool named `Dependency Walker` that you can get from [here](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)